# ajax control usage in a given scenario

Tags: ajax, asp.net-3.5

on pageload a panel must not be visible, onclick on a button some process will go on, that time i need to show the process in some notation and once the process is over i need to display the panel

Please help me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "I need to show the process is some notation"?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. One is to set the contents of the panel via `Document.getElementById("panel_id").innerHTML = "Your content here..."`

Another is to use CSS elements to have the panel hidden at load time. Then you change that attribute of the panel in your onclick code. For more details: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_visibility.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ajax, you have two main options:

1. Wrap your controls in an ASP.NET UpdatePanel control, and deal with the panel visibility in the code-behind.
2. Use javascript (jQuery recommended) to make ajax requests to WebMethods in the code behind, and when the request is successful, update the UI from the client-side.

I'd recommend option 1 for simplicity if you are new to ASP.NET/AJAX as it's easier to implement. To do this, you would have something like this:

Markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="MyPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <!-- panel contents here -->
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" OnClick="MyButton_Click" Text="Do Something"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something when the button is clicked

    //set the panel visible so that when this round trip is complete, the panel will show
    MyPanel.Visible = true;
}
```

The above would use ajax to process the button click event and you could do whatever you need and then set the panel to visible.